# Linear map of unit cube

Tags: linear-algebra, dimension-reduction

Let `c` be a vector of `n` constants and `X = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]` be a vector of `n` variables.

Assuming that `0 <= X <= 1`, I would like to compute the linear map `c.X`. This can be expressed with `Reduce`:

```
formula = Exists[Evaluate[X], y == c.X && Fold[#1 && 0 <= #2 <= 1 &, True, X]];
Reduce[formula, {y}, Reals]
```

With increasing `n`, the performance of this solution drops rapidly. Is there a better way to compute the solution `y`?

Comment: You cannot use `N` as a variable, it is a [reserved symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. For a given vector `c` you can quickly find the minimum and maximum values of `y` that allow a solution `X`.

Example for `n=10`:

```
n = 10;
c = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n]    (* random, to have an example *)
(*    {0.105518, -0.439788, -0.33041, -1.93738, -0.810956, 1.43839, -0.529671, 0.668688, 0.879621, 0.458327}    *)
X = Array[x, n]
(*    {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10]}    *)
Minimize[{c.X, And @@ Thread[0 <= X <= 1]}, X]
(*    {-4.0482, {x[1] -> 0., x[2] -> 1., x[3] -> 1., x[4] -> 1., x[5] -> 1.,
                x[6] -> 0., x[7] -> 1., x[8] -> 0., x[9] -> 0., x[10] -> 0.}}    *)
Maximize[{c.X, And @@ Thread[0 <= X <= 1]}, X]
(*    {3.55054, {x[1] -> 1., x[2] -> 0., x[3] -> 0., x[4] -> 0., x[5] -> 0.,
                 x[6] -> 1., x[7] -> 0., x[8] -> 1., x[9] -> 1., x[10] -> 1.}}    *)
```

So for this particular choice of the vector `c` there exists solutions `X` if $-4.0482 \le y \le 3.55054$. The convexity of the problem assures that all values of $y$ in this range give rise to solutions `X`.

The above code is fast and executes in about one second for $n=10^4$. For ultimate speed, call the [`LinearProgramming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html) function directly: you get the same results, but much faster:

```
X1 = LinearProgramming[c,
                       -IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray], 
                       ConstantArray[-1, n]];
X1.c
(*    -4.0482    *)
X2 = LinearProgramming[-c,
                       -IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray], 
                       ConstantArray[-1, n]];
X2.c
(*    3.55054    *)
```