# Linear map of unit cube (generalized)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

This question is a slight generalization of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209351/linear-map-of-unit-cube).

Let `M` be a fixed rational `m` $\times$ `n` matrix, e.g., `M = Rationalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n}], 0]`, and `X = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]` be a vector of n variables.

Assuming that `0 <= X <= 1`, I would like to compute the linear map `M.X`. This can be expressed with `Reduce`:

```
Y = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]], {i, m}]
formula = Exists[Evaluate[X], And@@Thread[Y == M.X] && And@@Thread[0 <= X <= 1]]
Reduce[formula, Y, Reals]
```

The solution `Y` forms a polyhedron. How can this polyhedron be efficiently computed with Mathematica? The solution above does not scale.

Another way of stating the problem is to compute a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ such that $\forall x: ~ x \in [0,1]^n \Leftrightarrow A M x \leq b$.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not scale"? What is the typical size for `m` and `n`? Is `m` greater or smaller than `n`. And what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, for a vector `Y`, you simply have to test whether `PseudoInverse[M].Y`  lies in the unit cube. Since the pseudoinverse `PseudoInverse[M]` may look pretty complicated when `M` is given symbolically, I suggest to do the computation of `PseudoInverse[M]` _numerically_.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think the question is about finding the convex polyhedron of all vectors `Y` for which `PseudoInverse[M].Y` lies in the unit hypercube. How do you parametrize the faces of this convex polyhedron as inequalities?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher also you need to be careful with *the* pseudoinverse: there are infinitely many pseudoinverses, and the question is: for which vectors `Y` does there exist any pseudoinverse `P` such that `P.Y` lies in the unit-hypercube. So you need to search over the space of pseudo-inverses.

Comment: You could of course calculate all images of the vertices of the unit hypercube with `P = Tuples[{0, 1}, n].Transpose[M]` and then try to find the convex hull of these points with `ConvexHullMesh[P]`. But this seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @Roman: Yes, I am looking for a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ such that $\forall x: x \in [0,1]^n \Leftrightarrow A M x \leq b$

Comment: Maybe ask at the https://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Roman: Thanks for your suggestion. I will wait a bit more for answers here before posting the question at https://math.stackexchange.com. BTW, I agree with your convex hull solution but I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: A reference can be found in the [answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179282/mathcalh-polyhedron-under-a-linear-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method that is a generalization of [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209355/26598) and should work for arbitrary $n$ and $m$. It is very efficient, as long as you don't want to do a graphics plot as below.

Let's do a random example where $m=3$ so we can visualize the polytope in 3D:

```
n = 5;
m = 3;
M = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, n}]
(*    {{-0.304994, -0.392532, 0.823638, -0.201907, 0.108934},
       {-0.100295, -0.66419, -2.50501, -0.483007, -0.982172},
       {0.00520204, -0.601936, 1.99376, 1.07407, -0.579136}}    *)
```

To calculate the facet normals, we take all length-$(m-1)$ tuples of columns of $M$, and for each such tuple calculate the vector that is perpendicular to all of them (via [`NullSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html)):

```
W = Join @@ NullSpace /@ Subsets[Transpose[M], {m - 1}]
(*    {{0.250025, -0.727159, 0.639318},
       {-0.176108, 0.576911, 0.797596},
       {-0.287587, 0.89256, 0.34732},
       {0.174337, -0.485727, 0.856549},
       {-0.876301, 0.0887525, 0.473518},
       {-0.878533, 0.475208, 0.0485508},
       {-0.355215, -0.50372, 0.787457},
       {0.739474, 0.55098, 0.386781},
       {-0.968459, -0.197213, 0.152295},
       {0.982782, 0.0000529691, 0.184769}}    *)
```

In this case, there are $\binom{n}{m-1}=\binom{5}{2}=10$ such facet normals. For each facet we use the linear programming trick of [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209355/26598) to get the minimum and maximum values of the scalar product with this facet normal, to find the boundaries of the polytope:

```
w = {#.LinearProgramming[#, -IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray], ConstantArray[-1,n]],
     #.LinearProgramming[-#, -IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray], ConstantArray[-1,n]]} & /@ (W.M)
(*    {{0., 4.66071}, {-1.84188, 0.613583}, {-3.57839, 0.},
       {-0.261406, 4.1875}, {-0.456861, 0.903485}, {-2.40775, 0.220539},
       {0., 3.86301}, {-1.85243, 0.}, {0., 1.18978},
       {-0.795815, 1.17771}}    *)
```

We can now assemble the inequalities that describe the polytope's facets, using the facet normals `W` and the associated scalar-product ranges `w`:

```
Y = Array[y, m];
F = And @@ MapThread[#2[[1]] <= #1.Y <= #2[[2]] &, {W, w}]
(*    0. <= 0.250025 y[1] - 0.727159 y[2] + 0.639318 y[3] <= 4.66071 &&
      -1.84188 <= -0.176108 y[1] + 0.576911 y[2] + 0.797596 y[3] <= 0.613583 &&
      -3.57839 <= -0.287587 y[1] + 0.89256 y[2] + 0.34732 y[3] <= 0. &&
      -0.261406 <= 0.174337 y[1] - 0.485727 y[2] + 0.856549 y[3] <= 4.1875 &&
      -0.456861 <= -0.876301 y[1] + 0.0887525 y[2] + 0.473518 y[3] <= 0.903485 &&
      -2.40775 <= -0.878533 y[1] + 0.475208 y[2] + 0.0485508 y[3] <= 0.220539 &&
      0. <= -0.355215 y[1] - 0.50372 y[2] + 0.787457 y[3] <= 3.86301 &&
      -1.85243 <= 0.739474 y[1] + 0.55098 y[2] + 0.386781 y[3] <= 0. &&
      0. <= -0.968459 y[1] - 0.197213 y[2] + 0.152295 y[3] <= 1.18978 &&
      -0.795815 <= 0.982782 y[1] + 0.0000529691 y[2] + 0.184769 y[3] <= 1.17771    *)
```

To show the polytope:

```
J = ImplicitRegion[F, Evaluate@Y];
RegionPlot3D[J, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

To show off, let's do this for `n=20` and `m=3`: we get $\binom{20}{2}=190$ facet normals, 380 inequalities, and an almost ellipsoidal polytope:

[image]